# Next Js getStaticProps getting lost

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In Next,

I have _app.js with:

```
const app = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

    return <div>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
           </div>
 }
```

and index.js with

```
export default function Index({ state }) {

return (
    <>  
        <Feed state={state} />
    </>
)
}


export async function getStaticProps({ preview = false }) {


let menu = [
    [
        "Home",
        "/"
    ]
    [
        "News",
        "/news/"
    ]
];

state.menu = menu;

return {
    props: { state, preview }
}
}
```

This works fine for route / but when I hit route /news the pageProps in _app.js are lost? Surely I don't have to call getStaticProps on every page?

And yes, I am a Next noob :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props) method is specific to the page in question; for you, that's the home/index page (`/`). So no, `state.menu` won't be available for the `/news` page as well.

In order for you to have the `menu` state for **every** page, you can utilise the `getInitialProps` method in `_app.js`.

Like so:

```js
// pages/_app.js

import App from "next/app";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  let menu = [
    ["Home", "/" ],
    ["News", "/news/"], 
  ];

  return {
    ...appProps,
    pageProps: {
      ...appProps.pageProps,
      state: { menu },
    },
  };
}

export default MyApp;
```

```js
// pages/news.js

export default function News({ state }) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(state.menu, null, 2));
  // [
  //   [
  //     "Home",
  //     "/"
  //   ],
  //   [
  //     "News",
  //     "/news/"
  //   ]
  // ]
  return null;
}
```

There are some [caveats](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats) to be aware of though, so you should give that a read before going into production.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your lucid response. Would a acceptable pattern be to load remote data here too?

Comment: @JohnSourcer You're welcome. If it's app-wide data, yeah; I see a lot of devs do this on projects. Do keep an eye on [React 18 / Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18) though, as I think the landscape is changing a bit in the near future.